# funciones pasadas por parametros o funciones callback

Tags: c++

Varias preguntas:

- ¿En qué casos se utilizan las funciones `callback`?
- ¿Se pueden utilizar en clases?
- ¿Funcionan de manera similar que en **javascript**?
- ¿Cómo se pasa una función por medio de un parámetro?
- Al momento de declarar los parámetros de la función ¿Cual es su tipo?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> ¿En qué casos se utilizan las funciones `callback`?

Es una pregunta demasiado amplia para ser contestada de manera concreta, por ello lo mejor es dar una respuesta amplia: cuando sea necesario.

- El patrón de diseño [Visitor](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_(patr%C3%B3n_de_dise%C3%B1o)) puede implementarse con callbacks (aunque también puede implementarse sin ellas).
- Las funciones de respuesta a eventos, suelen implementarse mediante callbacks.

---

> ¿Se pueden utilizar en clases?

Claro. Igual que cualquier otro dato, una callback puede ser un miembro de una clase, teniendo estas funciones:

```
int suma      (int a, int b) { return a + b; }
int resta     (int a, int b) { return a - b; }
int multiplica(int a, int b) { return a * b; }
int divide    (int a, int b) { return a / b; }
```

Y esta clase que contiene una *callback*:

```
class Clase
{
    int (callback*)(int, int);
public:
    Clase(int (operación*)(int, int)) : callback(operación) {}
    int operar(int a, int b) { return callback(a, b); }
};
```

Podemos hacer lo siguiente:

```
Clase a(suma), b(resta);
std::cout << a.operar(1, 2) << '\n'; // muestra 3
std::cout << b.operar(1, 2) << '\n'; // muestra -1
```

---

> ¿Funcionan de manera similar que en **javascript**?

No. Existen muchas diferencias entre las funciones de JavaScript y las de C++:

- JavaScript es un lenguaje de [tipado dinámico](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tipado_din%C3%A1mico).
- Las funciones JavaScript aceptan una cantidad de parámetros indeterminados.
- Las funciones JavaScript pueden ser usadas como funciones o como objetos.

  - Creando una función con `new`, ésta actuará como una clase, el `this` del objeto creado apuntará a si mismo y el valor de retorno de la función es descartado.
  - Creando una función sin `new` el `this` apunta al ámbito global (que en navegadores será el objeto `window`) y el valor de retorno puede ser capturado por cualquiera que llame a la función.

---

> ¿Cómo se pasa una función por medio de un parámetro?

Lo hemos visto hace dos apartados:

```
int funcion_que_recibe_una_funcion(int (*parametro)(int, int), int a, int b)
{
    return parametro(a, b);
}
```

Dado que C++ es un lenguaje de [tipado fuerte](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tipado_fuerte), cualquier parámetro que apunte a una función necesita conocer **todos** los tipos que forman parte de la función, es decir: el tipo de retorno y los tipos de los parámetros. Funciones con diferentes parámetros y diferentes tipos de retorno tendrán tipos diferentes. Así que para crear una variable de tipo función (*callback*) en C++ haremos lo siguiente:

```
tipo_de_retorno (nombre_de_la_variable)( ... lista de parametros ... );
```

Por lo tanto...

```
// funcion que devuelve int y recibe dos int
int (a)(int, int);
// funcion que no devuelve ni recibe nada
void (b)();
// funcion que devuelve un string y recibe un puntero constante a char y un int
std::string (c)(const char *, int);
```

Normalmente esta sintaxis es confusa, así que se suelen usar `typedef`:

```
typedef int (i_ii)(int, int);
typedef void (v_v)();
typedef std::string (s_ci)(const char *, int);

int funcion_que_recibe_una_funcion(i_ii *parametro, int a, int b)
{
    return parametro(a, b);
}

void funcion_que_recibe_una_funcion(v_v *parametro)
{
    parametro();
}

std::string funcion_que_recibe_una_funcion(s_ci *parametro, const char *a, int b)
{
    return parametro(a, b);
}
```

Date cuenta que hemos añadido `*` para indicar que estamos recibiendo un puntero a función; por otro lado el `typedef` suele ser considerado confuso también, así que se añadieron los alias a partir de C++11:

```
using i_ii = int(int, int);
using v_v = void();
using s_ci = std::string(const char *, int);
```

También podemos usar alias de plantilla para hacer los punteros a función aún más sencillos:

```
template <typename RETORNO, typename ... PARAMETROS>
using funcion = RETORNO(PARAMETROS ...);

int funcion_que_recibe_una_funcion(funcion<int, int, int> *parametro, int a, int b)
{
    return parametro(a, b);
}

void funcion_que_recibe_una_funcion(funcion<void> *parametro)
{
    parametro();
}

std::string funcion_que_recibe_una_funcion(funcion<std::string, const char *, int> *parametro, const char *a, int b)
{
    return parametro(a, b);
}
```

Y también podemos añadir el puntero directamente a los `typedef` o alias:

```
typedef int (*p_i_ii)(int, int);
typedef void (*p_v_v)();
typedef std::string (*p_s_ci)(const char *, int);

using ap_i_ii = int(*)(int, int);
using ap_v_v = void(*)();
using ap_s_ci = std::string(*)(const char *, int);

template <typename RETORNO, typename ... PARAMETROS>
using puntero_a_funcion = RETORNO(*)(PARAMETROS ...);
```

---

> Al momento de declarar los parámetros de la función ¿Cual es su tipo?

El tipo de los parámetros de la función no cambia, un parámetro de tipo `T` será de tipo `T` siempre.

Answer (score 3):

> ¿En qué casos se utilizan las funciones callback?

No hay una norma estricta sino que más bien depende de cada proyecto. Sin embargo las librerías gráficas suelen hacer uso de callbacks para lanzar los eventos ante acciones del usuario (click sobre un botón, tecla pulsada, etc...)

> ¿Funcionan de manera similar que en javascript?

En líneas generales NO. Piensa que JavaScript posee un tipado bastante débil mientras que en el caso de C++ sucede todo lo contrario. Esto tiene sus implicaciones ya que usos que pueden funcionarte en JS no van a ser viables en C++ porque el compilador se va a quejar.

Por supuesto siempre hay mecanismos para saltarse estas protecciones, pero por la salud de tu programa no te recomiendo hacerlo salvo que estés muy seguro de en dónde te estás metiendo.

> ¿Cómo se pasa una función por medio de un parámetro?

Usando C++ *antiguo* podríamos decir que un puntero a función tiene la siguiente forma:

```
[tipo de retorno] (*[nombre_variable])([parametros])
```

Un ejemplo:

```
void func(int a, float b)
{
  std::cout << a << ' ' << b;
}

int main()
{
  void (*funcPtr)(int,float) = func;

  funcPtr(1,2.5);
}
```

Y esto mismo se repite si en vez de una variable es un argumento:

```
void func(int a, float b)
{
  std::cout << a << ' ' << b;
}

void funcionDelegada(void (*funcPtr)(int,float))
{
  funcPtr(1,2.5);
}

int main()
{
  funcionDelegada(func);
}
```

Como ves el ejemplo empieza a ser complicado de leer. En estos casos lo mejor es declarar un alias:

```
void func(int a, float b)
{
  std::cout << a << ' ' << b;
}

typedef void(*PunteroAFunc)(int,float);

void funcionDelegada(PunteroAFunc funcPtr)
{
  funcPtr(1,2.5);
}

int main()
{
  funcionDelegada(func);
}
```

Sin embargo la sintaxis sigue siendo algo fea. Esto cambia a partir de C++ con el uso de `std::function` (librería `functional`:

```
void func(int a, float b)
{
  std::cout << a << ' ' << b;
}

using PunteroAFunc = std::function<void(int,float)>;

void funcionDelegada(PunteroAFunc funcPtr)
{
  funcPtr(1,2.5);
}

int main()
{
  funcionDelegada(func);
}
```

Otra ventaja de `std::function` es que admite tanto lambdas como objetos con el operador función:

```
int Suma(int a)
{
  return a + 5;
}

struct Acumulador
{
  static int acum;

  int operator()(int a)
  { return a + acum++; }
};

int Acumulador::acum = 1;

using PunteroAFunc = std::function<int(int)>;

int main()
{
  std::vector<PunteroAFunc> funciones
  {
    Acumulador(),                                        // 0 + 1 = 1
    Acumulador(),                                        // 1 + 2 = 3
    Suma,                                                // 3 + 5 = 8
    [](int a) { std::cout << a << std::endl; return a; } // Imprime 8
   };

  int a = 0;
  for( auto func : funciones )
  {
      a = func(a);
  }
}
```

> Al momento de declarar los parámetros de la función ¿Cual es su tipo?

Esta respuesta ya ha sido contestada de forma implícita pero, por resumir: C++ se caracteriza por un tipado fuerte de los datos. Todo debe estar perfectamente tipado para que el compilador lo admita. Esto afecta también a los punteros a función, por lo que tanto el tipo que representa a dicho puntero como los tipos de sus argumentos han de estar perfectamente definidos en el código fuente.

El tipado fuerte evita muchos errores tontos y, sabiendo aprovechar esta característica, se le puede sacar mucho jugo al lenguaje.

Answer (score 2):

Funciones *callback* es el nombre *artístico*. Desde el punto de vista del lenguaje, no es más que un puntero a una función. Y, como cualquier otro tipo de dato, se usa cuando sea conveniente. No hay un *lugar concreto* en el que usarlas.

Un puntero a una función se define así:

```
TIPO_DEVUELTO ( *NOMBRE )( ARGUMENTOS... );
```

La función `qsort( )` es un ejemplo de donde se usan punteros a funciones:

```
void qsort( void *base, size_t nmemb, size_t size, int (*compar)( const void *, const void * ) );
```

El argumento `compar` es un **puntero a función**.

Si intentas pasar otro tipo de dato, el compilador no te dejará. Tienes que pasarle exactamente el tipo indicado:

```
int myCompar( const void *arg1, const void *arg2 ) {
  ...
  return 0;
}

qsort( arg1, arg2, &myCompar );
```

En C++, también existen los punteros a metodos:

```
void (C::* fptr)( int );
```

eso es un ejemplo de un puntero a función miembro (método) de la clase C que recibe un `int` como argumento y no devuelve nada.

A partir de C++11, dispones de mecanismos *alternativos* al uso de punteros a funciones: la clase `std::function`:

```
template< class R, class... Args > class function<R(Args...)>
```

puede entenderse como un tipo de *nivel superior* de puntero a función, capaz de albergar tanto punteros a funciones normales, como punteros a funciones miembro.

También a partir de C++11, puedes hacer uso de *funciones lambda*, que se *asemejan* a las funciones anónimas de Javascript; su explicación merece un artículo completo.